# Cant get to an object in my JSON result

Tags: json, node.js

xml2js to take my xml result so that i can access the values. I am having some problems trying to access GetProvidersResponse and iterate through GetProvidersResult and Providers. How can I access these items?

```
{ 'xmlns:s': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' }
{ GetProvidersResponse: 
   { '@': { xmlns: 'http://www.kareo.com/api/schemas/' },
     GetProvidersResult: 
      { '@': [Object],
        ErrorResponse: [Object],
        SecurityResponse: [Object],
        Providers: [Object] } } }
```

when i try console.log(resultObject.GetProvidersResponse) i get undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the fallowing console.log(result['s:Body'].GetProvidersResponse.GetProvidersResult.Providers.ProviderData[0]);

and was able to see the data.